# How to get environment variable in play scala Framework 2.5.0?

Tags: scala, playframework, environment-variables

PFB the code which I used for getting environment variable but it is not working.

In application.conf

clientId = ${?clientId}

In Filters.scala

sys.env.get("clientId");

But it is "None".

If I type env in the respective environment, I could see the proper clientId which I set.

clientId = ba6ecff4-4aec-4298-8e98-f1f0b320249f

What is the right way to get the environment variable in Play Framework for scala 2.5.0?

Comment: `System.getenv("clientId")`

Comment: I am getting none for the above command as well.

Comment: what do you mean by "typing env in respective environment". How did you set the environmental variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You override the value. Change the property name

Correct:

```
myClientId = ${?clientId}
```

Wrong:

```
clientId = ${?clientId}
```

[Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionConfiguration):

> Because you can reference variables from within other variables,
>   ensure you don’t name your environmental variable the same as the
>   field name.